# Show Spinner Until ASP.NET ReportViewer Control Apears

Tags: asp.net, spinner, reportviewer, rdlc, progress

Using ASP.NET 4.5 .aspx page with ReportViewer for displaying RDLC reports.
When the page is loaded (especially for the first time) it takes sometimes more then 10 sec.
So, the users need some progress indication like a Spinner etc. until the report is shown.
Is there a solution for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452449/how-do-i-show-a-loading-spinner-when-submitting-for-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mv

Comment: DTs, the case there is different in 2 major point:
1. There the submit button in the same window starts the spinner, here the .aspx page with the ReportViewer opens in new browser window.
2. ASP.NET MVC controller/view there, and here is .aspx

Comment: @N.D.B were you able to solve this? Please share how you did it

Comment: Too old issue - Sorry, can't remember.