# display "please wait" image while saving data to database asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net MVC 3 with bootstrap. I am looking for "please wait" image
while saving my data to database.

please share me latest ones.

Thanks,
Surya.

Comment: What do you mean by "please wait image"? Do you mean like the fontawesome animated spinner?

Comment: yes. basically it freezes the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452449/how-do-i-show-a-loading-spinner-when-submitting-for-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452449/how-do-i-show-a-loading-spinner-when-submitting-for-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mv)